# PopupWindow dismiss

Tags: android

When I use `dismiss` to remove a popup window, does it only hide it or removes it from memory?

I tried `dismiss`, then `showAtLocation` several times (using the same PopupWindw object, not re-creating it) and the window was displayed and hidden without problems. The question is can I count on it - perhaps it is marked for deletion by the GC, but hasn't been garbage-collected yet?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dismiss()` is opposite to `showAtLocation()`, the object remains in a valid state after `dismiss()`. So it is safe to toggle `dismiss()/showAtLocation()`

It can be seen from the Android source code in here - you can look at `dismiss()` and `showAtLocation()` implementations

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#PopupWindow.showAtLocation%28android.view.View%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/PopupWindow.java#PopupWindow.dismiss%28%29

Answer (score 1):

An object will not be marked for deletion as long as you have a reference to it. So you can re-show it later.

Answer (score 0):

You could force the use of Garbage Collector using

`System.gc()`

Comment: Thanks. But It doesn't matter to me when it is collected, only if it is collected. If it is, then I need to create the popup window a new each time I need to display it.

Comment: Of course this is collected. Just think that a smartphone does not have a big memory, so the less allocated items you have, the more your app will be smooth.

Comment: The GC occures at the end of the execution of your class. If the GC conciders you won't use it again, it will be automatically collected.